# String position find opening div in string

Tags: php, html, variables, strpos

I try to find `'<video'` string in this variable that contains html

```
$string="<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="" muted="" poster="" preload="auto" style="width: 354.09836065574px; height: 600px; max-height:600px;;display:block;margin:0 auto;"><source src="" type="video/mp4" /> <source src="" type="video/webm" />
<div class="badge-item-animated-img">&nbsp;</div> "
```

So I use :

```
if (strpos($string, '<video')){
   echo $string;
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: What output you are expecting

Comment: strpos can return a value that is evaluated at false, like in your example, the position is `0`, you need to test against `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because strpos returns the current position of the tag 'video', which is 0 in your case. In PHP this is the same as false. Try this instead:

```
if (strpos($string, '<video') !== false){
     echo $string;
 }
```

Comment: TNX THIS WORKS! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$string='<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="" muted="" poster="" preload="auto" style="width: 354.09836065574px; height: 600px; max-height:600px;;display:block;margin:0 auto;"><source src="" type="video/mp4" /> <source src="" type="video/webm" />
    <div class="badge-item-animated-img"> </div> ';

if (strpos($string, '<video') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Note that the use of `!== false` is deliberate; `strpos` returns either the offset at which the needle string begins in the haystack string, or the boolean `false` if the needle isn't found. Since 0 is a valid offset and 0 is "falsey", we can't use simpler constructs like `!strpos($a, 'are')`.